# WooCommerce Subscriptions: Changing payment method of existing subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, woocommerce-subscriptions

A client of mine wants to change payment service provider in his WooCommerce store. He has a few hundred existing subscriptions that need to be transferred to this new PSP. Basically, everything is done in order to do this, except for the configuration in WooCommerce. WooCommerce needs to know to use the new payment plugin's code to renew subscriptions. I know of the existence of [this integration method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/payment-gateway-integration/change-payment-method-admin/) but that's not the issue. That integration allows you to add the required metadata to orders (like credit card tokens) in the WooCommerce UI. That has already been done. I changed the `_payment_method` post meta of a test subscription to my payment method identifier and I set `_requires_manual_renewal` identifier to `false` however, for some reason in the UI it still says `Manual Renewal` under payment method.

What things do I have to change in the database in order to change the payment method?

Comment: What's the payment gateway your client used and what's the new payment gateway?

Comment: @MichaelT Hey! The client used a form of SEPA direct debit that didn't work that well. This is the old payment gateway: https://github.com/mollie/WooCommerce and the new one is: https://github.com/spryngpayments/woocommerce The new one is much more stable as it supports mandates. All the customers already have signed mandates and the required user meta is already in the database

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with either of those plugins. My only advice is to make sure you're following [this guide here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/add-or-modify-a-subscription/#section-15).

Comment: @MichaelT I don't think this issue actually has a lot to do with the plugins themselves, but rather with the way WooCommerce reads data to find out which payment gateway to use. Thanks for the article though. I'll have a look.

Comment: Once submitted, a suscriptions is handled by the payment gateway herself, where customer has given his credentials and approve the transaction. Woocommerce just remind that and make the recurring orders and notify admin and customer… **So change of payment gateway for existing subscriptions is just not possible…**.